# Able to send images over socket but not text files

Tags: java, image, sockets, text

My client can send Images normally to server, but when it comes to text files they arrive empty. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I'd really appreciate help, because I have been trying to make this work for many days now. Thanks.

Here is the server code:

```
class TheServer {

    public void setUp() throws IOException { // this method is called from Main class.
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1991);
        System.out.println("Server setup and listening...");
        Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connect");
        System.out.println("Socket is closed = " + serverSocket.isClosed());



        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String str = rd.readLine();
        System.out.println("Recieved: " + str);
        rd.close();



        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

        int bufferSize = connection.getReceiveBufferSize();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/" + str);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);


        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

        int count;

        while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        is.close();
        connection.close();
        serverSocket.close();


    }
}
```

and here is the client code:

```
public class TheClient {

    public void send(File file) throws UnknownHostException, IOException { // this method is called from Main class.
        Socket socket = null;
        String host = "127.0.0.1";

        socket = new Socket(host, 1991);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("File is too large.");
        }

        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        wr.write(file.getName());
        wr.newLine();
        wr.flush();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        int count;

        while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }


        out.flush();
        out.close();
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are prematurely closing `BufferedReader` on server side before reading all the data. This essentially closes the connection.
2. You should not use `Reader` or `Writer` for non-character streams like binary image data. And you should not mix `BufferedReader` with any other stream wrapper for the same stream since it may read as many data as it fills in buffer.

Comment: 1. Hi, im pretty new to socket stuff so could you please tell me  how it should have been made?
2. How bad mistake is that?

Comment: @RohitMalish 1. Obviously you shouldn't close the stream if you're expecting more data to be read. 2. It can lead to unexpected behavior. I'd recommend to follow some beginner tutorials on Java sockets.