# Android print to network printer

Tags: android

I want to include feature in my android app to print image from network printer through WiFi. I tried below code, posted on stackoverflow, but I am only able to print text :( What to do if I want to print images.

```
try
{
    Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.222", 9100);
    PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        oStream.println("HI,test from Android Device");
        oStream.println("\n\n\n");
        oStream.close();
        sock.close(); 
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994899/able-to-send-images-over-socket-but-not-text-files

Comment: no this is not helping to print image

Comment: what issue are you facing when you try and send image....can you please share the logcat for our reference.

Comment: in above code, we are using println function so it used to only print text..... I have changed above code a little bit and created a OutputStream object from socket output stream. then I used write function and send byte array of string and it is printing well.... but when I pass byte array of image then it is printing only binary form of data instead of image....

Comment: code: void PrintImage(String name, String age, byte[] image) throws Exception {
  try {
   Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.XXX", 9100);

   OutputStream oStream = sock.getOutputStream();
   oStream.flush();

   String lineBreak = "\r\n";
   String dataLine = "\tName : \t\t" + name + "\t\tAge : \t"+ age + "";

   oStream.write(dataLine.getBytes());
   oStream.flush();

   
   oStream.write(lineBreak.getBytes());
   oStream.flush();
   
   oStream.write(image);
   oStream.flush();

   oStream.close();

   sock.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   throw e;
  }
 }

Comment: code you posted in question is not working even for text.

Comment: @KetanAhir Can you please see my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094911/how-to-give-print-command-to-printer-from-android-app

Comment: @mercury Can you please see my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094911/how-to-give-print-command-to-printer-from-android-app